# Secondary battery not found?

Tags: power-management, battery, dock, docking

I've got a Asus TX300 running Ubuntu 13.04. This is a laptop tablet hybrid which has secondary battery in the dock. This battery is not detected by Ubuntu as far as I can see.

Ran this while docked:

```
user@TX300:/sys/devices/platform$ dmesg |grep batt
[    1.691787] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
```

Also looked in `/sys/class/power_supply/` and other tips I've found, but there's no trace of the extra battery.

Any help appreciated.

Edit:

I ran the battery all the way down until the unit suspended. When I closed the lid after it hibernated the led indicator changed from blinking to static, indicating it was charging. When I woke up this morning it had indeed been charged by the secondary battery but it still doesn't seem to be found by the OS.

Comment: I also get more battery life without dock than with dock, probably due to the hardware in dock consuming power without the dock battery being utilized. batterylife displayed with dock 3:53, without dock 5:16.

Comment: Sorry, no answer, but a pointer to LinLap page where this has been discussed and where hopefully someone might post something to make progress with this. http://www.linlap.com/asus_transformer_book_tx300